# Why am I not getting CSRF warning from django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

So usually when you try to make a `POST` request to the server in Django without CSRF token it gave you this page
[image]

but for the past 3 months I've been playing with DRF and custom user model and I didn't even realized until now that I've actually not been getting that error despite not using CSRF in my postman header.

There's also some more details made it more confusing to me

- first I made a post request to `TokenObtainPairView` from `djangorestframework_simplejwt`
  containing username and password (I'm using base user model) for login and it was successful
- Right after that I made another post request to add a title (a model that only have 1 field which is a charfield)
  and then it gave me CSRF warning

I also have an almost identical project to this the only difference being the other projects uses custom user model and it never gave me any CSRF warning. So I suspect this has something to do with the user model somehow

So to summarize my question:

1. Why doesn't it gave me CSRF warning in the first POST request?
2. does this have anything todo with custom user model? if so what am I missing?
3. can anyone hypothesize about what's going on?

any keyword or a link or something would be appreciated I'm interested to learn more !

EDIT:

I've found the potential problem. So I didn't really know what `has_perm` and `has_module_perms` mean so I just set it as the following:

```
def has_perm(self, *args, **kwargs):

        return True

def has_module_perms(self, *args, **kwargs):

        return True
```

could this be the actual issue?

Comment: It might depend on the authentication system you are using as well as your middleware. If I use ```jwt token``` authentication and wrap my functional rest views in decorator ```@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])``` it uses jwt and no ```csrf``` is required. However, if I remove the decorator, it defaults to ```session based``` authentication and ```csrf_token``` is required. I'm sure there are many possibilities.

Comment: @sintribu Hello sir I've edited the question based on your feedback!

Comment: csrf token it's for the forms in Django. Check this link to know the auth process with DRF https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/